# In Javascript, Why do we have to use the undefined keyword?

Tags: javascript

I have a hashmap, and i'm doing a check to see if a key is not undefined. However, my code only works when I specify that. For instance:

```
if (map[key] !== undefined) {
   /* code will run */
}
```

This code works as expected. However, I wanted to shorten the code to just:

```
if (map[key]) {
   /* code will not run */
}
```

Shouldn't these two be the same thing? The code will still run but I only get the expected output for the first code snippet.

Comment: What if `map[key]` is set, but equal to `false` or `null`?

Comment: You'd probably be better with `if (key in map) {...`

Comment: They are not the same, the code runs in the second snippet because `map[key]` is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and that's all the `if` condition needs to pass.

Comment: Also of note - `{ foo: undefined}` will *have* the key `foo` but the value of it is explicitly `undefined`. That's different to trying to get `bar` from it - in that case the key does *not* exist.

Comment: In Javascript, to check whether a variable is defined, you should always use the following: `if(typeof(map[key]) !== 'undefined')`

Comment: @Klaassiek that doesn't check if a variable is defined. It checks if fetching the property returns `undefined`. If the variable `map` was *not* declared, you'd still get a ReferenceError with this code because you'd have to read it to get the properties. Also same if `key` was not declared - it would still need to be read for the expression to be evaluated which would still result in ReferenceError. With that said, it's ***EXTREMELY*** bad practice to ever have to deal with possible undeclared variables. Just don't. Use `const`/`let` and strict mode.

Comment: @VLAZ: true that. But I explicitly mentioned ‘variable’. Not property. To access a property of the variable, the variable itself needs of course to be an Object.

Comment: @Klaassiek there are two variables in your expression: `map` and `key`. Yet, the expression checks neither of the two, it checks the property of `map` where the property is named with the value of `key`. Therefore, your expression checks a property, not a variable.

Comment: @VLAZ: As for using undefined checks: checking for third-party libraries is a good example of having to use checks for the existence of some variable. If the variable is defined, the library has loaded. This example checks whether the cdn can provide jQuery, and if not, it loads a locally stored version of the library: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-load-jquery-locally-when-cdn-fails/amp/

Comment: @Klaassiek use `window.jQuery`. Done.

Comment: And you are right about the property vs variable situation. The example was not in place.

Comment: If you want a hashmap, you should use a `new Map()` and not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check `if (map[key])` that is saying "does this value appear to be falsey".  Any value can be passed to an if statement, so what happens when you pass a string `'foo'` - will it be `true` or `false`?

Lots of other value types can evaluate to a boolean-like value, which is why you want to check for the specific value with `map[key] !== undefined` in some cases, and in others you might not. It just depends.

Run this demo to see how the different value types are treated here

```js
var arr = [0, 1, '', 'a', true, false, null, undefined];

arr.forEach((val) => {
  console.log(`${val} is a ${typeof val}`);
  
  if (val) {
    console.log(' - truthy');
  }

  if (val !== undefined) {
     console.log(' - not undefined');
  }
});
```

Comment: "*Lots of other value types can evaluate to a boolean-like value*" - **everything** in JS can be coerced to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "will not run". If the key you're accessing has a boolean value of false it will NOT run.
ie

```
const map = {};
map['something'] = false;
```

if (map['something']) will not run (regardless if the key is there or not).

> Note map['something'] could have been false, NaN, '', undefined, 0,
> all which would return false.

```js
(() => {

// when using Map object.
const map = new Map();
map.set(4, true);

// you get the value by using .get() not [].
console.log(map.get(4));
// true

// when using object literal
const map2 = {};
// you can access the key using []
map2[4] = true;
console.log(map2[4]);
// true
console.log(map2[4] === true ? true : false);
// true

})();
```

A more accurate way to determining if a key exists is to use hasOwnProperty. Do NOT use `in` as it includes prototype properties as well.

Example:
if (map.hasOwnProperty(THE_SEARCHED_FOR_KEY)){ ... }

Comment: Don't use `map.hasOwnProperty()` either, that'll break if anyone stores a value with the key `"hasOwnProperty"` in the map. Use `Object.hasOwn(map, …)` instead.

Comment: @Bergi I mean every object suffers the same problem if they overwrite the property. If I did Object.hasOwn = false; it's going to make your recommended function inoperable. (exception frozen object)

Comment: No. The point is not that the method could be overwritten by malicious code, but that the property can be shadowed by a *legitimate* value - one, even, that might come from user input or external systems. For example, `const map = {"something": false, "4": true, "hasOwnProperty": "oops"};` - it does not require messing with `Object.hasOwn` or `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`.